# A reference of a narration where Ibn Abbas takes off an amulet while reciting Qu'ran 2:165

Tags: hadith, tafseer, source-identification

I recently came across this where it said

[Ibn Abi Hatim reported about Hudhaifah (May Allaah be pleased with him):

He saw a man with a piece of twine on his hand (as a protection or cure from fever) so he cut the twine and read the verse: “Most of them believe in Allaah and still practise Shirk (polytheism).” (Quran, 12:106)... Hudhaifah’s reciting the verse of Quran is a clear-cut proof that Companions used to recite the verses dealing with the major Shirk to condemn minor Shirk. As Ibn Abbas (May Allaah be pleased with him) did by reciting the verse from Surah Al-Baqarah. (Quran, 2:165]

I see that the reference for Hudhaifah is from Ibn Abu Hatim but where is this referecnce from Ibn Abbas?

Comment: What is the source of your quote?

Comment: Here is the Englsih website i saw it on:http://navedz.com/wearing-ring-amulets-talismans-is-shirk/  and Here's the Arabic version https://shkhudheir.com/scientific-lesson/1568643818